How to count the number of times an alert has fired over a period of time?
Using Prometheus and Grafana I need to display how mamy times a particular alert has fired over a 24h period (last 24h, yesterday, 2days ago and a week ago).
I have used this query to calculate the last 24h
count(count_over_time(ALERTS{alertstate="firing"}[1d])) by (alertname)

this one for the day before
count(count_over_time(ALERTS{alertstate="firing"}[1d] offset 1d)) by (alertname)

and so on.
However, looking at my Slack notification channels(my only route), the number of times I see some alerts there does not correlate with what these queries return. eg. some alerts I cannot see notifications for, but they're returned by the query, and some that I have multiple notifications for but the query returns only 1.
I've tried multiple different queries, including this approach, but each gave me incorrect results.

Do you want to try this method?
A brief explanation: According to Alin Sînpălean, the metric ALERTS_FOR_STATE returns the number of transitions from pending to firing. (However, based on my own testing, it doesn't seem very accurate and may include other situations.)
LeoHsiao suggested creating a custom recording rule to filter out only the firing state from ALERTS_FOR_STATE. (in my understanding)
Then, by applying aggregation functions (e.g., change, sum, etc.) to this custom metric, it should effectively calculate how many times an alert was triggered.
I’ve summarized it below, but still recommend referring to the original link.
Solution Overview

Add a Recording Rule:
Start by adding a Recording Rule to your Prometheus configuration. This rule will record alerts that are in the "firing" state, allowing you to track changes in alert status.
groups:
  - name: recording_rules
    rules:
      - record: ALERTS_FOR_STATE:firing
        expr: ALERTS_FOR_STATE and ignoring(alertstate) ALERTS{alertstate="firing"}


Create a Query in Grafana:
In Grafana, use the following PromQL query to count the number of times each alert has been fired over the past week:
sum(changes(ALERTS_FOR_STATE:firing[1w]) + 1) by (alertname)


changes(ALERTS_FOR_STATE:firing[1w]): Calculates how many times the ALERTS_FOR_STATE:firing metric has changed in the last week, effectively counting transitions to the "firing" state.
+ 1: Accounts for the initial firing event, as the changes function doesn’t count the first state change. ( it's from GPT's Answer, but I'm not sure about this meaning, since I change this number or remove it, the results will change to a impossible value. )
sum(... ) by (alertname): Aggregates the count by each alert name.




Zolpidem, a link to a solution is welcome, but ensure your answer is useful without it: Provide at least a technical summary of how the problem is solved, so it can be reproduced without the link. It's not enough to advertise what it achieves. Also, add context around the link so others have some idea what it is and why it is there. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
